# откуда берётся 0?

Tags: python

Хочу проверить число на четность , не понимаю откуда берётся 0 .

```
a = 2

for i in range(a):
    if  not i % 2 == 1:
        print(i, 'чётное число')
    else:
        print(i, 'нечётное число')
```

Comment: Обновил ответ. Теперь полный. А вообще, если что-то странное получается, то смотрите сначала на синтаксис. И до синтаксиса алгоритм аккуратно продумывайте. Если ответ ниже был полезным, его можно отметить плюсом (нажать треугольник вверх слева от вопроса). Если ответ полностью решил задачу - принять ответ (нажать на галку под треугольниками слева).  Можно и то, и другое, если сильно понравилось:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам цикл вообще не нужен (пример без него - ниже). А 0 вы получаете, так как сами цикл запускаете, начиная с 0. Полная запись: `for in in range (0,2,1)` - начинаем с 0 (включительно), идём с шагом 1, до 2 не доходим согласно синтаксису `range`.

```
a = 2
if  not a % 2 == 1:
    print(a, 'чётное число')
else:
    print(a, 'нечётное число')
```

Comment: Как по мне, стоит убрать `not` и просто переставить принты местами

Comment: И число, насколько я знаю, стоит брать по модулю, для такой логики

Comment: @iKuzmychov, у меня не стояло задачи переписать код полностью, иначе бы я его тернарным оператором в одну строку поместил (примерно так: `print('нечётное число' if a % 2 else 'чётное число')`). Мне надо было показать автору вопроса, что в его коде ему надо было убрать, чтобы заработало.

Comment: Я не спорю, но раз автор вопроса пытается понять, как определить чётность числа, модуль в ответ точно следует добавить

Comment: @iKuzmychov, про "по модулю" - математически, да наверное. Я математику плохо помню, я с точки зрения кодирования уже данного алгоритма замечания делал. Мой ответ вам к первому вашему комменту относился.